# No graphical output in postscript terminal of Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am currently trying to make the xlabel in italics.

What I did first what to set the terminal to postscript.(I've checked whether it is included in the gnuplot that I've installed using the "set terminal" command)

```
gnuplot> set terminal

Available terminal types:
           canvas  HTML Canvas object
              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
          context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
            corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW
             dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
            eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment
              emf  Enhanced Metafile format
            emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials
         epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
              fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor
              gif  GIF images using libgd and TrueType fonts
             hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
             jpeg  JPEG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
            latex  LaTeX picture environment
              lua  Lua generic terminal driver
               mf  Metafont plotting standard
               mp  MetaPost plotting standard
             pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
              png  PNG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
       postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)



gnuplot> set terminal postscript Terminal type set to 'postscript' Options are 'landscape enhanced defaultplex \    leveldefault monochrome colortext \    dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 butt noclip \   nobackground \    palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \    "Helvetica" 14  fontscale 1.0 '
```

After setting the terminal to postscript, I did the following :-

```
gnuplot> set termoption enhanced

 gnuplot> set xlabel "{/Times-Italic italics}"
```

and then when I tried plotting the graph this happened but there's no graphical output. When I used the terminal q, there was a graphical output but I want to use the postscript terminal as I want my label to be italicized.

```
> gnuplot> plot "undouenergykyori.dat" u 1:2 w l %!PS-Adobe-2.0
> %%Creator: gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5 %%CreationDate: Sun Dec  4
> 13:54:24 2016 %%DocumentFonts: (atend) %%BoundingBox: 50 50 554 770
> %%Orientation: Landscape %%Pages: (atend) %%EndComments %%BeginProlog
> /gnudict 256 dict def gnudict begin % % The following true/false flags
> may be edited by hand if desired. % The unit line width and grayscale
> image gamma correction may also be changed. % /Color false def
> /Blacktext false def /Solid false def /Dashlength 1 def /Landscape
> true def /Level1 false def /Level3 false def /Rounded false def
> /ClipToBoundingBox false def /SuppressPDFMark false def
> /TransparentPatterns false def /gnulinewidth 5.000 def /userlinewidth
> gnulinewidth def /Gamma 1.0 def /BackgroundColor {-1.000 -1.000
> -1.000} def % /vshift -46 def /dl1 {
>   10.0 Dashlength userlinewidth gnulinewidth div mul mul mul   Rounded { currentlinewidth 0.75 mul sub dup 0 le { pop 0.01 } if } if } def
> /dl2 {
>   10.0 Dashlength userlinewidth gnulinewidth div mul mul mul   Rounded { currentlinewidth 0.75 mul add } if } def /hpt_ 31.5 def /vpt_ 31.5
> def /hpt hpt_ def /vpt vpt_ def /doclip {   ClipToBoundingBox {
>     newpath 50 50 moveto 554 50 lineto 554 770 lineto 50 770 lineto closepath
>     clip   } if } def % % Gnuplot Prolog Version 5.1 (Oct 2015) % %/SuppressPDFMark true def % /M {moveto} bind def /L {lineto} bind def
> /R {rmoveto} bind def /V {rlineto} bind def /N {newpath moveto} bind
> def /Z {closepath} bind def /C {setrgbcolor} bind def /f {rlineto
> fill} bind def /g {setgray} bind def /Gshow {show} def   % May be
> redefined later in the file to support UTF-8 /vpt2 vpt 2 mul def /hpt2
> hpt 2 mul def /Lshow {currentpoint stroke M 0 vshift R    Blacktext
> {gsave 0 setgray textshow grestore} {textshow} ifelse} def /Rshow
> {currentpoint stroke M dup stringwidth pop neg vshift R   Blacktext
> {gsave 0 setgray textshow grestore} {textshow} ifelse} def /Cshow
> {currentpoint stroke M dup stringwidth pop -2 div vshift R    Blacktext
> {gsave 0 setgray textshow grestore} {textshow} ifelse} def /UP {dup
> vpt_ mul /vpt exch def hpt_ mul /hpt exch def   /hpt2 hpt 2 mul def
> /vpt2 vpt 2 mul def} def /DL {Color {setrgbcolor Solid {pop []} if 0
> setdash}  {pop pop pop 0 setgray Solid {pop []} if 0 setdash} ifelse}
> def /BL {stroke userlinewidth 2 mul setlinewidth  Rounded {1
> setlinejoin 1 setlinecap} if} def /AL {stroke userlinewidth 2 div
> setlinewidth  Rounded {1 setlinejoin 1 setlinecap} if} def /UL {dup
> gnulinewidth mul /userlinewidth exch def  dup 1 lt {pop 1} if 10 mul
> /udl exch def} def /PL {stroke userlinewidth setlinewidth     Rounded {1
> setlinejoin 1 setlinecap} if} def
> 3.8 setmiterlimit % Classic Line colors (version 5.0) /LCw {1 1 1} def /LCb {0 0 0} def /LCa {0 0 0} def /LC0 {1 0 0} def /LC1 {0 1 0} def
> /LC2 {0 0 1} def /LC3 {1 0 1} def /LC4 {0 1 1} def /LC5 {1 1 0} def
> /LC6 {0 0 0} def /LC7 {1 0.3 0} def /LC8 {0.5 0.5 0.5} def % Default
> dash patterns (version 5.0) /LTB {BL [] LCb DL} def /LTw {PL [] 1
> setgray} def /LTb {PL [] LCb DL} def /LTa {AL [1 udl mul 2 udl mul] 0
> setdash LCa setrgbcolor} def /LT0 {PL [] LC0 DL} def /LT1 {PL [2 dl1 3
> dl2] LC1 DL} def /LT2 {PL [1 dl1 1.5 dl2] LC2 DL} def /LT3 {PL [6 dl1
> 2 dl2 1 dl1 2 dl2] LC3 DL} def /LT4 {PL [1 dl1 2 dl2 6 dl1 2 dl2 1 dl1
> 2 dl2] LC4 DL} def /LT5 {PL [4 dl1 2 dl2] LC5 DL} def /LT6 {PL [1.5
> dl1 1.5 dl2 1.5 dl1 1.5 dl2 1.5 dl1 6 dl2] LC6 DL} def /LT7 {PL [3 dl1
> 3 dl2 1 dl1 3 dl2] LC7 DL} def /LT8 {PL [2 dl1 2 dl2 2 dl1 6 dl2] LC8
> DL} def /SL {[] 0 setdash} def /Pnt {stroke [] 0 setdash gsave 1
> setlinecap M 0 0 V stroke grestore} def /Dia {stroke [] 0 setdash 2
> copy vpt add M   hpt neg vpt neg V hpt vpt neg V   hpt vpt V hpt neg
> vpt V closepath stroke   Pnt} def /Pls {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt sub M
> 0 vpt2 V   currentpoint stroke M   hpt neg vpt neg R hpt2 0 V stroke 
> } def /Box {stroke [] 0 setdash 2 copy exch hpt sub exch vpt add M   0
> vpt2 neg V hpt2 0 V 0 vpt2 V   hpt2 neg 0 V closepath stroke   Pnt}
> def /Crs {stroke [] 0 setdash exch hpt sub exch vpt add M   hpt2 vpt2
> neg V currentpoint stroke M   hpt2 neg 0 R hpt2 vpt2 V stroke} def
> /TriU {stroke [] 0 setdash 2 copy vpt 1.12 mul add M   hpt neg vpt
> -1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V closepath stroke   Pnt} def /Star {2 copy Pls Crs} def /BoxF {stroke [] 0 setdash exch
> hpt sub exch vpt add M   0 vpt2 neg V hpt2 0 V 0 vpt2 V   hpt2 neg 0 V
> closepath fill} def /TriUF {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt 1.12 mul add M  
> hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V
> closepath fill} def /TriD {stroke [] 0 setdash 2 copy vpt 1.12 mul sub
> M   hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V
> closepath stroke   Pnt} def /TriDF {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt 1.12 mul
> sub M   hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul
> V closepath fill} def /DiaF {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt add M   hpt neg
> vpt neg V hpt vpt neg V   hpt vpt V hpt neg vpt V closepath fill} def
> /Pent {stroke [] 0 setdash 2 copy gsave   translate 0 hpt M 4 {72
> rotate 0 hpt L} repeat   closepath stroke grestore Pnt} def /PentF
> {stroke [] 0 setdash gsave   translate 0 hpt M 4 {72 rotate 0 hpt L}
> repeat   closepath fill grestore} def /Circle {stroke [] 0 setdash 2
> copy   hpt 0 360 arc stroke Pnt} def /CircleF {stroke [] 0 setdash hpt
> 0 360 arc fill} def /C0 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto vpt 90 450 arc}
> bind def /C1 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto   2 copy vpt 0 90 arc
> closepath fill    vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind def /C2 {BL [] 0 setdash
> 2 copy moveto     2 copy vpt 90 180 arc closepath fill    vpt 0 360 arc
> closepath} bind def /C3 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto    2 copy vpt 0
> 180 arc closepath fill    vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind def /C4 {BL [] 0
> setdash 2 copy moveto     2 copy vpt 180 270 arc closepath fill   vpt 0
> 360 arc closepath} bind def /C5 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto    2 copy
> vpt 0 90 arc  2 copy moveto   2 copy vpt 180 270 arc closepath fill
>   vpt 0 360 arc} bind def /C6 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto  2 copy
> vpt 90 270 arc closepath fill     vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind def /C7
> {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto    2 copy vpt 0 270 arc closepath fill
>   vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind def /C8 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto
>   2 copy vpt 270 360 arc closepath fill   vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind
> def /C9 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto    2 copy vpt 270 450 arc
> closepath fill    vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind def /C10 {BL [] 0
> setdash 2 copy 2 copy moveto vpt 270 360 arc closepath fill   2 copy
> moveto    2 copy vpt 90 180 arc closepath fill    vpt 0 360 arc closepath}
> bind def /C11 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto  2 copy vpt 0 180 arc
> closepath fill    2 copy moveto   2 copy vpt 270 360 arc closepath fill
>   vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind def /C12 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto
>   2 copy vpt 180 360 arc closepath fill   vpt 0 360 arc closepath} bind
> def /C13 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto   2 copy vpt 0 90 arc closepath
> fill  2 copy moveto   2 copy vpt 180 360 arc closepath fill   vpt 0 360
> arc closepath} bind def /C14 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy moveto   2 copy
> vpt 90 360 arc closepath fill     vpt 0 360 arc} bind def /C15 {BL [] 0
> setdash 2 copy vpt 0 360 arc closepath fill   vpt 0 360 arc closepath}
> bind def /Rec {newpath 4 2 roll moveto 1 index 0 rlineto 0 exch
> rlineto   neg 0 rlineto closepath} bind def /Square {dup Rec} bind def
> /Bsquare {vpt sub exch vpt sub exch vpt2 Square} bind def /S0 {BL [] 0
> setdash 2 copy moveto 0 vpt rlineto BL Bsquare} bind def /S1 {BL [] 0
> setdash 2 copy vpt Square fill Bsquare} bind def /S2 {BL [] 0 setdash
> 2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt Square fill Bsquare} bind def /S3 {BL []
> 0 setdash 2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt2 vpt Rec fill Bsquare} bind def
> /S4 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt sub vpt Square fill
> Bsquare} bind def /S5 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy 2 copy vpt Square fill
>   exch vpt sub exch vpt sub vpt Square fill Bsquare} bind def /S6 {BL
> [] 0 setdash 2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt sub vpt vpt2 Rec fill
> Bsquare} bind def /S7 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt
> sub vpt vpt2 Rec fill     2 copy vpt Square fill Bsquare} bind def /S8
> {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy vpt sub vpt Square fill Bsquare} bind def /S9
> {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy vpt sub vpt vpt2 Rec fill Bsquare} bind def
> /S10 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy vpt sub vpt Square fill 2 copy exch vpt
> sub exch vpt Square fill  Bsquare} bind def /S11 {BL [] 0 setdash 2
> copy vpt sub vpt Square fill 2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt2 vpt Rec
> fill  Bsquare} bind def /S12 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy exch vpt sub exch
> vpt sub vpt2 vpt Rec fill Bsquare} bind def /S13 {BL [] 0 setdash 2
> copy exch vpt sub exch vpt sub vpt2 vpt Rec fill  2 copy vpt Square
> fill Bsquare} bind def /S14 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy exch vpt sub exch
> vpt sub vpt2 vpt Rec fill     2 copy exch vpt sub exch vpt Square fill
> Bsquare} bind def /S15 {BL [] 0 setdash 2 copy Bsquare fill Bsquare}
> bind def /D0 {gsave translate 45 rotate 0 0 S0 stroke grestore} bind
> def /D1 {gsave translate 45 rotate 0 0 S1 stroke grestore} bind def
> /D2 {gsave translate 45 rotate 0 0 S2 stroke grestore} bind def /D3
> {gsave translate 45 rotate 0 0 S3 stroke grestore} bind def /D4 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S4 stroke grestore} bind def /D5 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S5 stroke grestore} bind def /D6 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S6 stroke grestore} bind def /D7 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S7 stroke grestore} bind def /D8 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S8 stroke grestore} bind def /D9 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S9 stroke grestore} bind def /D10 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S10 stroke grestore} bind def /D11 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S11 stroke grestore} bind def /D12 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S12 stroke grestore} bind def /D13 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S13 stroke grestore} bind def /D14 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S14 stroke grestore} bind def /D15 {gsave
> translate 45 rotate 0 0 S15 stroke grestore} bind def /DiaE {stroke []
> 0 setdash vpt add M   hpt neg vpt neg V hpt vpt neg V   hpt vpt V hpt
> neg vpt V closepath stroke} def /BoxE {stroke [] 0 setdash exch hpt
> sub exch vpt add M   0 vpt2 neg V hpt2 0 V 0 vpt2 V   hpt2 neg 0 V
> closepath stroke} def /TriUE {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt 1.12 mul add M  
> hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V
> closepath stroke} def /TriDE {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt 1.12 mul sub M  
> hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V
> closepath stroke} def /PentE {stroke [] 0 setdash gsave   translate 0
> hpt M 4 {72 rotate 0 hpt L} repeat   closepath stroke grestore} def
> /CircE {stroke [] 0 setdash    hpt 0 360 arc stroke} def /Opaque
> {gsave closepath 1 setgray fill grestore 0 setgray closepath} def
> /DiaW {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt add M   hpt neg vpt neg V hpt vpt neg V
> hpt vpt V hpt neg vpt V Opaque stroke} def /BoxW {stroke [] 0 setdash
> exch hpt sub exch vpt add M   0 vpt2 neg V hpt2 0 V 0 vpt2 V   hpt2
> neg 0 V Opaque stroke} def /TriUW {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt 1.12 mul
> add M   hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul
> V Opaque stroke} def /TriDW {stroke [] 0 setdash vpt 1.12 mul sub M  
> hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V   hpt 2 mul 0 V   hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V
> Opaque stroke} def /PentW {stroke [] 0 setdash gsave   translate 0 hpt
> M 4 {72 rotate 0 hpt L} repeat   Opaque stroke grestore} def /CircW
> {stroke [] 0 setdash    hpt 0 360 arc Opaque stroke} def /BoxFill
> {gsave Rec 1 setgray fill grestore} def /Density {   /Fillden exch def
> currentrgbcolor   /ColB exch def /ColG exch def /ColR exch def   /ColR
> ColR Fillden mul Fillden sub 1 add def   /ColG ColG Fillden mul
> Fillden sub 1 add def   /ColB ColB Fillden mul Fillden sub 1 add def  
> ColR ColG ColB setrgbcolor} def /BoxColFill {gsave Rec PolyFill} def
> /PolyFill {gsave Density fill grestore grestore} def /h {rlineto
> rlineto rlineto gsave closepath fill grestore} bind def % % PostScript
> Level 1 Pattern Fill routine for rectangles % Usage: x y w h s a XX
> PatternFill % x,y = lower left corner of box to be filled %   w,h =
> width and height of box %   a = angle in degrees between lines and
> x-axis %   XX = 0/1 for no/yes cross-hatch % /PatternFill {gsave /PFa [
> 9 2 roll ] def   PFa 0 get PFa 2 get 2 div add PFa 1 get PFa 3 get 2
> div add translate   PFa 2 get -2 div PFa 3 get -2 div PFa 2 get PFa 3
> get Rec   TransparentPatterns {} {gsave 1 setgray fill grestore}
> ifelse   clip   currentlinewidth 0.5 mul setlinewidth   /PFs PFa 2 get
> dup mul PFa 3 get dup mul add sqrt def   0 0 M PFa 5 get rotate PFs -2
> div dup translate   0 1 PFs PFa 4 get div 1 add floor cvi     {PFa 4 get
> mul 0 M 0 PFs V} for   0 PFa 6 get ne {   0 1 PFs PFa 4 get div 1 add
> floor cvi     {PFa 4 get mul 0 2 1 roll M PFs 0 V} for  } if   stroke
> grestore} def % /languagelevel where  {pop languagelevel} {1} ifelse
> dup 2 lt  {/InterpretLevel1 true def   /InterpretLevel3 false def}
>   {/InterpretLevel1 Level1 def     2 gt
>       {/InterpretLevel3 Level3 def}
>       {/InterpretLevel3 false def}     ifelse }  ifelse % % PostScript level 2 pattern fill definitions % /Level2PatternFill { /Tile8x8
> {/PaintType 2 /PatternType 1 /TilingType 1 /BBox [0 0 8 8] /XStep 8
> /YStep 8}     bind def /KeepColor {currentrgbcolor [/Pattern /DeviceRGB]
> setcolorspace} bind def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop 0
> 0 M 8 8 L 0 8 M 8 0 L stroke} 
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat1 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop 0 0 M 8 8 L 0 8 M 8 0 L stroke  0 4 M 4 8 L 8 4 L 4 0
> L 0 4 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat2 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop 0 0 M 0 8 L     8 8 L 8 0 L 0 0 L fill}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat3 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop -4 8 M 8 -4 L   0 12 M 12 0 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat4 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop -4 0 M 8 12 L   0 -4 M 12 8 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat5 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop -2 8 M 4 -4 L   0 12 M 8 -4 L 4 12 M 10 0 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat6 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop -2 0 M 4 12 L   0 -4 M 8 12 L 4 -4 M 10 8 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat7 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop 8 -2 M -4 4 L   12 0 M -4 8 L 12 4 M 0 10 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat8 exch def << Tile8x8  /PaintProc {0.5 setlinewidth pop 0 -2 M 12 4 L   -4 0 M 12 8 L -4 4 M 8 10 L stroke}
> >> matrix makepattern /Pat9 exch def /Pattern1 {PatternBgnd KeepColor Pat1 setpattern} bind def /Pattern2 {PatternBgnd KeepColor Pat2
> setpattern} bind def /Pattern3 {PatternBgnd KeepColor Pat3 setpattern}
> bind def /Pattern4 {PatternBgnd KeepColor Landscape {Pat5} {Pat4}
> ifelse setpattern} bind def /Pattern5 {PatternBgnd KeepColor Landscape
> {Pat4} {Pat5} ifelse setpattern} bind def /Pattern6 {PatternBgnd
> KeepColor Landscape {Pat9} {Pat6} ifelse setpattern} bind def
> /Pattern7 {PatternBgnd KeepColor Landscape {Pat8} {Pat7} ifelse
> setpattern} bind def } def % % %End of PostScript Level 2 code %
> /PatternBgnd {   TransparentPatterns {} {gsave 1 setgray fill
> grestore} ifelse } def % % Substitute for Level 2 pattern fill codes
> with % grayscale if Level 2 support is not selected. %
> /Level1PatternFill { /Pattern1 {0.250 Density} bind def /Pattern2
> {0.500 Density} bind def /Pattern3 {0.750 Density} bind def /Pattern4
> {0.125 Density} bind def /Pattern5 {0.375 Density} bind def /Pattern6
> {0.625 Density} bind def /Pattern7 {0.875 Density} bind def } def % %
> Now test for support of Level 2 code % Level1 {Level1PatternFill}
> {Level2PatternFill} ifelse % /Symbol-Oblique /Symbol findfont [1 0
> .167 1 0 0] makefont dup length dict begin {1 index /FID eq {pop pop}
> {def} ifelse} forall currentdict end definefont pop % /MFshow {    {
> dup 5 get 3 ge
>      { 5 get 3 eq {gsave} {grestore} ifelse }
>      {dup dup 0 get findfont exch 1 get scalefont setfont
>      [ currentpoint ] exch dup 2 get 0 exch R dup 5 get 2 ne {dup dup 6
>      get exch 4 get {textshow} {stringwidth pop 0 R} ifelse }if dup 5 get 0 eq
>      {dup 3 get {2 get neg 0 exch R pop} {pop aload pop M} ifelse} {dup 5
>      get 1 eq {dup 2 get exch dup 3 get exch 6 get stringwidth pop -2 div
>      dup 0 R} {dup 6 get stringwidth pop -2 div 0 R 6 get
>      textshow 2 index {aload pop M neg 3 -1 roll neg R pop pop} {pop pop pop
>      pop aload pop M} ifelse }ifelse }ifelse }
>      ifelse }    forall} def /Gswidth {dup type /stringtype eq {stringwidth} {pop (n) stringwidth} ifelse} def /MFwidth {0 exch { dup
> 5 get 3 ge { 5 get 3 eq { 0 } { pop } ifelse }  {dup 3 get{dup dup 0
> get findfont exch 1 get scalefont setfont
>      6 get Gswidth pop add} {pop} ifelse} ifelse} forall} def /MLshow { currentpoint stroke M   0 exch R   Blacktext {gsave 0 setgray MFshow
> grestore} {MFshow} ifelse } bind def /MRshow { currentpoint stroke M  
> exch dup MFwidth neg 3 -1 roll R   Blacktext {gsave 0 setgray MFshow
> grestore} {MFshow} ifelse } bind def /MCshow { currentpoint stroke M  
> exch dup MFwidth -2 div 3 -1 roll R   Blacktext {gsave 0 setgray
> MFshow grestore} {MFshow} ifelse } bind def /XYsave    { [( ) 1 2 true
> false 3 ()] } bind def /XYrestore { [( ) 1 2 true false 4 ()] } bind
> def Level1 SuppressPDFMark or  {} { /SDict 10 dict def systemdict
> /pdfmark known not {   userdict /pdfmark systemdict /cleartomark get
> put } if SDict begin [   /Title ()   /Subject (gnuplot plot)  
> /Creator (gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5)   /Author (SabrinaZuraimi) % 
> /Producer (gnuplot) %  /Keywords ()   /CreationDate (Sun Dec  4
> 13:54:24 2016)   /DOCINFO pdfmark end } ifelse % % Support for boxed
> text - Ethan A Merritt May 2005 % /InitTextBox { userdict /TBy2 3 -1
> roll put userdict /TBx2 3 -1 roll put
>            userdict /TBy1 3 -1 roll put userdict /TBx1 3 -1 roll put
>      /Boxing true def } def /ExtendTextBox { Boxing
>     { gsave dup false charpath pathbbox
>       dup TBy2 gt {userdict /TBy2 3 -1 roll put} {pop} ifelse
>       dup TBx2 gt {userdict /TBx2 3 -1 roll put} {pop} ifelse
>       dup TBy1 lt {userdict /TBy1 3 -1 roll put} {pop} ifelse
>       dup TBx1 lt {userdict /TBx1 3 -1 roll put} {pop} ifelse
>       grestore } if } def /PopTextBox { newpath TBx1 TBxmargin sub TBy1 TBymargin sub M
>                TBx1 TBxmargin sub TBy2 TBymargin add L
>          TBx2 TBxmargin add TBy2 TBymargin add L
>          TBx2 TBxmargin add TBy1 TBymargin sub L closepath } def /DrawTextBox { PopTextBox stroke /Boxing false def} def /FillTextBox {
> gsave PopTextBox 1 1 1 setrgbcolor fill grestore /Boxing false def}
> def 0 0 0 0 InitTextBox /TBxmargin 20 def /TBymargin 20 def /Boxing
> false def /textshow { ExtendTextBox Gshow } def % % redundant
> definitions for compatibility with prologue.ps older than 5.0.2 /LTB
> {BL [] LCb DL} def /LTb {PL [] LCb DL} def end %%EndProlog %%Page: 1 1
> gnudict begin gsave doclip 50 50 translate
> 0.100 0.100 scale 90 rotate 0 -5040 translate 0 setgray newpath (Helvetica) findfont 140 scalefont setfont BackgroundColor 0 lt 3 1
> roll 0 lt exch 0 lt or or not {gsave BackgroundColor C clippath fill
> grestore} if /Helvetica findfont 140 scalefont setfont /vshift -46 def
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 448 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 448 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 0)] ] -46.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 1080 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 1080 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 5x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-9)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 1712 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 1712 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 1x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-8)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 2344 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 2344 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 1.5x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-8)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 2975 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 2975 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 2x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-8)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 3607 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 3607 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 2.5x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-8)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 4239 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 4239 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 3x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-8)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 4871 M 63 0 V 6002 0 R
> -63 0 V stroke 798 4871 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 3.5x10)] [(Helvetica) 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-8)] ] -60.7 MRshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 882 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 882 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 0)] ] -46.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 1748 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 1748 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 1x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 2615 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 2615 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 2x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 3481 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 3481 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 3x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 4348 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 4348 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 4x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 5214 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 5214 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 5x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 6081 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 6081 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 6x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 6947 448 M 0 63 V 0 4360 R 0 -63 V stroke 6947 308 M [ [(Helvetica) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 ( 7x10)] [(Helvetica)
> 112.0 70.0 true true 0 (-21)] ] -60.7 MCshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor
> 1.000 UL LTB LCb setrgbcolor 882 4871 N 882 448 L 6065 0 V 0 4423 V
> -6065 0 V Z stroke
> 1.000 UP
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor LCb setrgbcolor 3914 98 M [ [(Times-Italic) 140.0 0.0 true true 0 (italics)] ] -46.7 MCshow LTb %
> Begin plot #1
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor /Helvetica findfont 140 scalefont setfont LCb setrgbcolor 6296 4738 M ("undouenergykyori.dat" u 1:2) Rshow
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor 6380 4738 M 399 0 V 882 825 M 473 1624 V 1184 566 V 560 314 V 355 78 V 216 146 V
> -28 -75 V 121 -19 V 24 77 V 38 63 V 42 159 V 29 -27 V 20 5 V
> -5 -102 V 30 112 V 30 -28 V 23 171 V 69 -40 V
> -14 -28 V 65 77 V 29 9 V
> -31 -42 V 109 54 V 16 107 V 44 -10 V
> -58 -111 V 64 136 V 45 10 V 17 -126 V 45 76 V 8 56 V 3 -98 V 21 21 V 42 18 V 34 32 V 50 135 V
> -5 -183 V 60 214 V 0 -211 V 42 139 V
> -3 33 V 42 -141 V 22 206 V 45 -179 V 1 -5 V 17 194 V 39 -87 V 16 0 V 67 66 V 0 -192 V 14 214 V 19 -170 V 46 -5 V 60 156 V
> -35 -93 V 45 54 V 38 25 V 11 50 V 48 -95 V 23 -33 V 26 141 V 39 66 V 21 -80 V 9 -43 V 47 100 V 64 -138 V
> -34 93 V 59 -63 V 36 -39 V 16 78 V 21 -130 V 9 18 V 72 89 V 43 25 V
> -10 72 V 11 -107 V 16 -63 V 69 96 V 22 40 V 29 -140 V 6 117 V 58 59 V 59 16 V 41 -96 V
> -2 73 V
> -23 176 V 45 -252 V 73 -33 V 50 113 V 63 -93 V 12 -13 V 50 3 V
> -12 -6 V 123 79 V 27 -85 V
> -18 74 V 70 -80 V
> -35 70 V 92 152 V 31 -47 V
> -9 -191 V % End plot #1 stroke
> 2.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor
> 1.000 UL LTB LCb setrgbcolor 882 4871 N 882 448 L 6065 0 V 0 4423 V
> -6065 0 V Z stroke
> 1.000 UP
> 1.000 UL LTb LCb setrgbcolor stroke grestore end showpage
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, so I just copy-and-pasted the whole terminal output. I'm sorry it is so long..

Comment: Sorry. Found out that I can actually make my labels italic in the default qt terminal. But I'm still wondering why there is no graphical output when I switch to the postscript terminal..

Comment: You asked for postscript and it gives you a postscript file (starts with the header `%!PS-Adobe-2.0`). Is that what you're confused about?

Comment: Ah, I see! I didn't really understand the meaning of changing the terminal to the postscript. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for `postscript` and it gave you [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript). Terminals such as this just write the output in the appropriate format, and gnuplot isn't supposed to give a graphical window showing you what it looks like.

You can write the PostScript to a file by adding the line

```
set output "output.ps"
```

somewhere before you plot, and then view the file `output.ps` with your favorite PostScript document reader.

Not producing a graphical window is nice for batch jobs or scripting. For example, when writing a paper, I usually write a build script that calls gnuplot to build my plots as `.eps` (or `.pdf`)---often many files.  These are then used in my LaTeX file. If you have many plots or important dependencies, this is especially helpful.  I run one script and it builds everything as needed.  This ability to be scripted is one reason gnuplot is so useful.

---

You may want to consider using "encapsulated PostScript" (.eps) with the terminal option `eps`.  EPS is the same output as `postscript`, but with a bounding box around it (it also has a different file header, but is otherwise the same format). What you would want depends on whatever you are using your PostScript for. You can also put terminal options on the same line as the `set terminal`:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! It helps a lot as I do not know much about gnuplot

Comment: You also seem to be using the interactive mode (typing commands at the `gnuplot>` prompt) instead of using gnuplot scripts (all the commands in a text file). It's easier to keep track of what you did and reproduce the same results with a script. I only use the interactive mode to look up `help` documentation. I recommend [Gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/), which is a nice tutorial website that explains many basics and advanced capabilities. (Most other sites just give the internal help documentation or command grammars with little or no explanation.)